# TFS 2008 with VS 2010 (Beta 2)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild

My experience with TFS is limited. We run Team Foundation Server off a build server I will denote as 'Alice.' Alice has been working great until we ugraded to VS 2010; and with the urgency of a build coming up in the next few weeks, my question is how do we get a successful build? I followed the instructions listed here: http://richardsbraindump.blogspot.com/2009/11/how-to-build-vs2010-solutions-using.html, however the build fails. My pathway towards the solution: had me put VS 2010 on Alice, instead of turning off the build service and turning it back on, I simply restarted the server*, modified a pathway as it was listed (previously "" and Norton Ghost 2003 gave me a problem with that in the beginning).

*denotes possible problem

What happens: CI_X.1 - Failed - 
Any help (including something as simple as analyzing the summary to own experience with the two environments would be much appreciated)

Update: found this error:
 C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(373,7): error MSB4131: The "Reason" parameter is not supported by the "GetBuildProperties" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a gettable public instance property.

Answer (score 2):

We are using VS2010 RC connecting to TFS 2008.

The solution we've done for now is to modify the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets file that was located in C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild folder.

Remove the line `<Output TaskParameter="Reason" PropertyName="Reason" />`

This appears to be an issue where its a new feature on TFS2010 that was added to the build.targets file. Since the feature doesn't appear to be in TFS2008 and the Microsoft Connect has closed the ticket, it seems to be the best option for now.

This of course leads to another bug that raises the error: MSB4131: The "AssociatedChangesets" parameter is not supported by the "GenCheckinNotesUpdateWorkItems" task.

From the Microsoft Connect, this will be fixed in the RTM. The workaround is to add `<SkipGetChangesetsAndUpdateWorkItems>true</SkipGetChangesetsAndUpdateWorkItems>` to your TFSBuild.proj file.

And then I was finally able to build .NET 4.0 solution under TFS2008.